# Custom binding valueAccessor has unexpected result

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I am stumped by the following behavior in a custom binding of knockout.js:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        console.log( JSON.stringify(value) );
    }
}

ko.applyBindings({
    someText: ko.observable("inital value")
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: someText, customBinding: {some: 'option'}">
```

The `valueAccessor()` *should* give me the view model property that is bound to the value of the element (i.e. the observable `someText`). To quote the docs:

> `valueAccessor` — A JavaScript function that you can call to get the current model property that is involved in this binding. Call this without passing any parameters (i.e., call `valueAccessor()`) to get the current model property value.

However, what it *really* does is return the binding value, i.e. `{some: 'option'}`.

What am I missing?

See http://jsfiddle.net/j5y8H/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the model property you want for your valueAccessor in your custombinding call. In your case, you want the model property 'someText' :

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: someText, customBinding: someText">
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/j5y8H/1/

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense. It does not work the way I expected it, but it's consistent with the way the `value` binding works, for example. It's just not consistent with the way the documentation states it. `valueAccessor` will be whatever you care to pass in the binding, not necessarily the "the current model property". Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Anything else you pass along you can pick up from the allBindingsAccessor. I've made a quick example where I pass along a string in a property called 'source' here : http://jsfiddle.net/j5y8H/3/ (or you can pick up the 'value' property like Grim points out)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing things up a bit - the *valueAccessor* parameter gives access to the value **of your binding** (like you found out already).

The "value" binding, on the other hand, is just another binding that might not even be present on the element where yours is applied - or not be valid at all (e.g. on a div).

If you really want to access the property that is bound to the *value* binding (and most likely if you do you might want to rethink your binding handler), you can do so through the *allBindingsAccessor* parameter, like that:

```
ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().value);
```

Comment: Yes, I found that one as well by now. :-) In fact I was mislead by the documentation, or rather I misread it. My plan is to build a custom binding that creates a jQueryUI datepicker (for example) and I'd like to inject an object into the binding that contains options for it. Much like the `template` binding works.

Comment: I don't know how jQuery datepicker workse, but i did something similar for some MooTools date picker addon, and i found out that handling the value updates and events directly within my handler, bypassing completely the use of the value binding, lead to much less headaches. :)